# What roles do abstract/cosmic entities play?

Tags: comics, marvel

In the Marvel universe there are apparently [a lot of cosmic entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_entity_%28Marvel_Comics%29).  What specific ones appear in this panel from Avengers Academy?  Why don't they seem to react to or notice Giant-Man/the Absorbing Man?  Why do there seem to be this four hanging around together?

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, they look suitably ominous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Left to Right:

> - **[Eon/Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28comics%29)**: Responsible for choosing the Protectors of the Universe, mortal champions elected to face one specific menace to life
>     in the universe each. Killed by Maelstrom, but succeeded by its
>     "daughter" Epoch.
> - **[the Inbetweener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-Betweener)**:  Represents the synthesis between all concepts within the universe, such as life and death, order and chaos,
>     love and hate, god and man, impotence and omnipotence. However, it
>     resents its servitude to Order and Chaos, and has tried to break free
>     several times.
> - **[Lord Chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Chaos_%28Marvel_Comics%29)**: Embodies the universal concept of Chaos. Opposite of Master Order. Together with Master Order, Lord Chaos
>     claims to be responsible for assigning fates to mortals. Likened to
>     vengeance by the Living Tribunal. Master Order and Lord Chaos created
>     the In-Betweener as a balance between them.
> - **[The Living Tribunal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Tribunal):** The Living Tribunal is the judge of the cosmic entities who ensures that the cosmic laws are obeyed and
>     safeguards the multiverse from mystical imbalance.

They do not seem to notice Giant Man because he is not doing anything they need to be concerned with. The appearance of mortals in the Realm of Abstract Entities is generally ignored unless they are doing something worthy of notice such as altering reality over a wide swath of the universe or disturbing some aspect of the balance of the Universe which could later cause a catastrophic event.

Mortals have to work to be noticed, and only significant humans such as the Sorcerer Supreme, Adam Warlock or Thanos have ever had their attention at all.

As to why those particular four are hanging out together, that may simply be for the benefit of the readers who may be impressed by the images of the cosmic entities, but who actually do not need to BE together to be together. They are abstract entities whose powers are so vast they can alter reality to suit their needs, so tiny issues such as space, or time or distance really don't mean anything to them, they can project themselves or their essence to communicate with each other whenever/wherever they like.

I liken the cosmic entities to an immune system for the Universe. They protect the Universe from diseases (or conditions/beings/technologies) that might alter the space-time continuum, the magical balance or the natural order of the Universe. Each universe has their own representations of these entities and they may not always be the same or function as effectively.